# What are my options for GUI based Administration & Management of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tools

I have been given the task of working with PostgreSQL 9.1. I have previously worked with Microsoft SQL, and had used the SQL Management Studio. I had used Oracle's SQL developer as well as TOAD when I had to deal with Oracle.

When Compared to such tools, the pgAdmin seems rather limited. I have checked the list at http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools#Lightning_Admin_for_PostgreSQL but many of links I checked were dead.

I would like something which gives me the following features:

- Import and Export of data into various formats like .xls/.xlsx, .csv
  etc
- Ability to see the data in the tables without having to click so much. (for example, in Oracle's SQL developer, once I sign in, I can see the data in my tables in 3 clicks; In pgAdmin, I have to navigate through the hierarchy, to reach my table, and then rightclick to get the 'View Top 100 Rows option')
- Append data from an external source (.xls/.csv) to an existing Table.
- Intelisence/ Code Completion while writing SQL commands.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my question.

Comment: Did you check SQL Workbench/J (it's in the Wiki list). It fullfills those requirements (it can't *import* XLS though).

Comment: I use EMS SQL Manager.  I could do everything with it I wanted so far minus pgagent job handling.  It has its own glitches, but so far I haven't found a replacement.

Comment: I use console and it's best tool for PostgreSQL. You learn your database schema, SQL, imports, BASH scripts everyday so you are better everyday :). You have also SQL code completion there using tab. All graphical tools are too slow for me.

Comment: @sufleR While mostly you're right, a graphical DB browser can be the difference between success and failure.  There is no chance for example that I always remember all the few thousand objects in my database, but running through them I can find them easily.  YMMV, however...

Comment: check EnterpriseDB PEM. http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-enterprise-manager

Comment: @Hz.Root Can you please post that as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: dbForge Studio for PostgreSQL is available at https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/studio/ .

Answer (score 2):

you can check EnterpriseDB PEM. http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/products/postgres-enterprise-manager

Answer (score 1):

I use SQL Manager For Postgres by www.sqlmanager.net.
Although there is no code completion, there is a free (lite) version you can try (and use) for free.

I reccomend it

Comment: There __is__ code completion.  What's more, you can set whether you want it for every keyword and object or (say) you don't want it for functions.

Comment: Can you link to the free lite version? All I could find was the trial version.

Comment: On the donwload page there is a link for Lite version:
http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/manager/download
It's named: "EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL Freeware".


As for code completion, I didn't use it, and honestly didn't even search for it. But if it's there - great ;)